# Converting a relationship table into domain objects, Static or Instance method?

Tags: oop, orm, domain-object

Suppose we have 2 tables 'Departments' & 'Users'. There is also another table called 'UserDeps' for user<->department relation. For the first 2 tables we have 2 classes for domain objects. There is a layer in the app. for converting tables into objects and vice versa.

Now The Problem:
I have a method like this:
List GetDepartmentUsers(long depid);

My question is : Where do you put this method?

1. As a static method inside 'Department' class? ( obviously syntax would be something like this :

`List<Users> GetDepartmentUsers(long depid, DataHelper dh);`

2. As an instance method for every 'Department' object?

`Department dep = new Department(depid);`

`DataHelper dh = new DataHelper();`

`dep.GetDepartmentUsers(dh);`

Note: 'DataHelper' is a class which handles DB/SQL operations.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the whole context, just based on what is provided, the second solution is better. A Department has Users, therefore, it makes sense to ask a Department to get the list of its Users.

The first one is not object-oriented. Because static method is just a function not a method in OO sense. Such functions kill the purpose of OO.